I've made this discord.js command for my bot which makes the bot go offline
The command makes the bot go offline, and before doing so, it sends an embed message saying it's going offline, but I'm not to sure why it won't work.
After trying the command, the message "the application didn't respond" shows up on discord.
Here's the code, any help would be helpful
client.on('InteractionCreate', (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.commandName === 'bot-going-offline' && message.author.id === owner_ID) {
      const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setTitle("Gababes bot is going offline")
      .setDescription("gababes bot is now offline no commands will work")
      .setColor("DarkRed");

        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] }).then(() => {
            client.destroy();
            process.exit(); 
        });
    }
});


message is not initialized, so the owner check fails, leaving the bot with nothing to execute or reply. This is probably because you referenced code from when message commands were a thing?
You can use interaction to get the user ID, so the condition can be rewritten to:
interaction.user.id === owner_ID

